# .htaccess redirect based on language in uri

Tags: .htaccess

I have MVC structure for my project: `example.com/class/function/param`

I have `http://example.com/` or `http://example.com/project/` based on that if project is in root folder or sub-folder.

My **goal** is redirect:

```
http://example.com/ -> http://example.com/en/ 
http://example.com/project/ -> http://example.com/project/en/
```

`http://example.com/**en**/` should be replaced with language equivalent ( e.g.: /**de**/, /**ru**/, ...) so in pseudocode:

```
{base_url}/{lang}/{class}/{function}/{param}
```

Define **`http://example.com`** as relative path!

Then I can select first segment of url ( /en/ ) and change language with my function.

My current **.htaccess** file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Prevent file browsing
Options -Indexes
```

**Edit:**

Considering `Router.php` class to handle URL rewriting...

Comment: `http://example.com/**en**/ should be replaced with language equivalent` This part to be done via .htaccess OR your php code?

Comment: With .htaccess. I will generate internal links with BASE_URL constant in PHP.

Comment: But how will .htaccess get to know other `language equivalent`. I don't see `language equivalent` part of URL any where.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it directly with htaccess. You will be able to get user language, but not to use this information to construct the url exactly as you want it to be (if in htaccess you get fr_FR, you won't be able to only put fr in your URL).

You will have to do url rewriting with PHP. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16389034/2806497